# what does flatten do in sequential model in keras

Tags: neural-network, keras, flatten, keras-layer

I'm studying keras with sequential model.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 128, input_length=text_max_words))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

what does Flatten do in here?

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [the relevant documentation](https://keras.io/layers/core/#flatten), which contains a nice example:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3,
                 border_mode='same',
                 input_shape=(3, 32, 32)))
```

**before**: `model.output_shape == (None, 64, 32, 32)`

```
model.add(Flatten())
```

**after**: `model.output_shape == (None, 65536)`

Explaining this final shape:

- `None` is like an empty placeholder, that will be waiting for the size of a batch
- `65536` is the result of running *flatten* on the input dimensions:

  ```
  `64 * 32 * 32 == 65536     # True`
  ```

#### Comparison to NumPy

It is similar to the `flatten()` function from NumPy. Here is a mini example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: A = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(3, 3))

In [3]: A
Out[3]: 
array([[9, 6, 5],
       [3, 4, 6],
       [6, 7, 9]])
```

> Now perform the flattening action:

```
In [4]: A.flatten()
Out[4]: array([9, 6, 5, 3, 4, 6, 6, 7, 9])
```

So we can see the matrix (a.k.a. the rank-two tensor) has been flattened, here row-wise.